# looping de php e javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, select

tenho esse código php que mostra um select com dados do banco e preciso criar um botão que toda vez que clicado adicionasse um novo select igual a esse para o usuario fazer a seleção, acredito que seria feito com javascript, isso é possível?

segue meu select

```
<tr>
<td>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-description itemRow" id="itemRow_1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="itemRow_1"></label>
</div>
</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td>
<div class="row m-1" id="selects">
<select name="xpto[]" class="form-control">
<?php
$query = $conn->query("SELECT descricao FROM itens order by descricao asc");
while ($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
echo '<option value="' . $reg["descricao"] . '">' . $reg["descricao"] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>                                               
</div>
</td>
<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" value="0" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Considerando que vc já gerou a estrutura `HTML` dinamicamente através do `PHP`, ou seja, que a `table` com o `tbody, tr, td, inputs, selects, options` já esta pronta, acredito que seja viável para solucionar sua questão **clonarmos** a estrutura já pronta.

Podemos fazer isso utilizando **`HTML DOM Element cloneNode()`**, com esse método conseguiremos replicar toda a estrutura sem muito esforço. Para mais informações sobre esse método acesse o [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp).

Uma observação que faço é que o `name` do `select` e `inputs` sejam `array`, por exemplo, declare-os assim **`name="xpto[]"`**, para que no `back-end` vc consiga pegar esses valores enviados.

```
<select name="xpto[]" class="col-md-3 m-1">
    [código php para gerar as opções conforme busca no banco de dados]
</select>
```

Para a clonagem funcionar criei um `id` chamado `selects` e o atribui ao `tbody` da `table`, isso é muito importante, pois vc precisará realizar essa alteração para que ao renderizar a tabela a primeira vez esse identificador esteja presente.

```
<!--tabela-->
<table>
    <!--tbody onde acrescentei o id 'selects'-->
    <tbody id="selects">
    [...]
```

Depois criei um `link` para executar a clonagem e usando `Bootstrap` formatei-o com a classe `btn btn-primary` para deixá-lo igual a um botão.

```
<!--Botão para chamar a função de clonagem-->
<aside class="m-1">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add()">Add</a>
</aside>
```

Repare que no evento `onclick` chamo a função `add()` a qual escrevi para realizar a **clonagem**.

```
function add() {
    //cria uma constante que receberá o elemento que será clonado, no caso tudo que está entre a tag tr  
    const node = document.getElementById("selects").lastElementChild
    //passa o parâmetro true para clonar o nó seus atributos e descendentes
    const clone = node.cloneNode(true)
    //cria uma variável para manipular o tbody
    let tbody = document.getElementById("selects")
    //insere um novo nó na estrutura do DOM de um documento, no caso insere uma nova tr no tbody
    tbody.appendChild(clone)        
}
```

Abaixo o código completo para teste.

```js
function add() {
            //cria uma constante que receberá o elemento que será clonado, no caso tudo que está entre a tag tr  
            const node = document.getElementById("selects").lastElementChild
            //passa o parâmetro true para clonar o nó seus atributos e descendentes
            const clone = node.cloneNode(true)
            //cria uma variável para manipular o tbody
            let tbody = document.getElementById("selects")
            //insere um novo nó na estrutura do DOM de um documento, no caso insere uma nova tr no tbody
            tbody.appendChild(clone)        
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--tabela-->
    <table>
        <!--tbody onde acrescentei o id 'selects'-->
        <tbody id="selects">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-description itemRow" id="itemRow_1">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="itemRow_1"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row m-1">
                        <select name="xpto[]" class="form-control">
                            <option value="descricao1">Descricao 1</option>
                            <option value="descricao2">Descricao 2</option>
                            <option value="descricao3">Descricao 3</option>
                        </select>                                               
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" value="0" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!--Botão para chamar a função de clonagem-->
    <aside class="m-1">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add()">Add</a>
    </aside>
```

Comment: sim funcionou, no meu aso tenho um selectbox e um seletor numeral na mesma linha, seria possível duplicar a linha inteira ao invés de apenas o select? deixarei editado na pergunta o código completo

Comment: Aproveitei que vc editou a pergunta e reformulei a resposta. :D

Comment: Sim exatamente isso, ajudou muito, porem caso eu exclua todos os selects que estão selecionados, na hora de adicionar um novo ele não cria, teria como deixar essa linha de requisição fixa para caso o usuário excluir todas ele possa inserir uma nova sem precisar recarregar a pagina?

Comment: Legal! Mas se a resposta foi realmente útil pra vc não se esqueça de aceitá lá. Já quanto à exclusão,  uma sugestão seria vc criar uma outra função que captura o `tbody` conta quantas `tr` tem e exclui todas exceto a última, para sempre deixar uma opção sem ter que fazer o reload da página.